# Union of subgroups of $G$ when $G$ is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, cyclic-groups

"Let $G$ be a cyclic non-trivial group (infinite or not) and $T$ be the union of all proper subgroups of $G$. Prove that either $T$ is empty or it is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if the order of $G$ is a prime power"

I'm guessing I have to take seperately whether $G$ is finite or not. If finite I'm trying to use Lagrange theorem, but I dont really know where to start... So to summarize, I have to prove that:

$$T= \emptyset  ~~\text{ or }~~T < G~⟺~o(G)=p^n$$

where $p$ is a prime number and $n$ is any non-negative integer.

Comment: That is not what you need to prove. The premise is that $T$ is empty or a **subgroup**. It's always a subset.

Comment: The infinite case can be dealt directly. If $G$ is finite, and $|G|=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$ is a prime factorization of $|G|$ with $r\gt 1$, find elements of orders $p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$ and $p_1^{a_1}$, and consider any subgroup that contains both those elements. Then remember that a cyclic group is never a union of proper subgroups.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I don't really understand your point. which case are you trying to hint me about ? finite or infinite ? and also, why would you assume $|G|$ has a prime factorization when it is supposed to be a prime power ?

Comment: It says, explictly: "if $G$ is finite, and..." so would that be a discussion of the infinite case, or the finite case? I am hinting that you should try to do the contrapositive: if the order of $G$ is **not** a prime power, then $T$ is not a subgroup and is not empty.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Well, you started your hint by saying "the infinite case can be dealt directly". I wrongly assumed you developed more on this, anyway thanks I'll try to dot this :)

Answer (score 2):

**Lemma.** A group $G$ is a union of proper subgroups if and only if $G$ is not cyclic.

*Proof.* If $G$ is not cyclic, then $\cup_{g\in G}\langle g\rangle = G$ expresses $G$ as a union of proper subgroups. If $G$ is cyclic and $G=\cup_{i\in I} H_i$ with $H_i$ a subgroup of $G$, then let $g\in G$ be a generator of $G$. Then $g\in \cup_{i\in I} H_i$, so there exists $i\in I$ with $g\in H_i$. Since $H_i$ is a subgroup, we have $G =\langle g\rangle\leq H_i\leq G$, so the $H_i$ are not proper subgroups. $\Box$

**Lemma.** A group $G$ has no proper nontrivial subgroups if and only if $G$ is cyclic of prime order.

*Proof.* Omitted. $\Box$

Thus $T=\varnothing$ if and only if $G$ is of prime order and cyclic, so we may assume $T\neq\varnothing$ and $G$ is not cyclic of prime order.

If $G$ is infinite, then it is isomorphic to the additive group of integers, so we may take $G=\mathbb{Z}$. Then $2,3\in T$, since $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $3\mathbb{Z}$ are proper subgroups of $G$. If $T$ were a subgroup, then $2,3\in T$ implies $1\in T$, hence $T=G$. But $G$ is cyclic, hence it is not a union of proper subgroups. Thus, $T$ cannot be a subgroup in this case.

Now assume $G$ is finite. If $G$ is not of prime power order, $|G|=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$, $r\gt 1$, with the $p_i$ pairwise distinct and $a_i\gt 0$, we know that if $d$ divides $|G|$ then $G$ has a unique subgroup of order $d$ and in particular has elements of order $d$. Let $a\in G$ be of order $p_1^{a_1}$, and let $b$ be of order $p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$. Then $\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle b\rangle$ are proper nontrivial subgroups of $G$, so $a,b\in\langle a\rangle\cup\langle b\rangle\subseteq T$.

Any subgroup of $G$ that contains both $a$ and $b$ must contain $ab$. Since $a$ and $b$ commute, and are of relatively prime order, then the order of $ab$ is the least common multiple of the orders of $a$ and $b$. That means that $|ab| = |G|$, so $ab$ is a generator of $G$.

Since $G$ cannot be equal to $T$ (because $G$ is cyclic), and $T$ contains $a$ and $b$, then $T$ cannot be a subgroup of $G$.

Thus, if $G$ is cyclic and it is not of prime power order, then $T$ is not a subgroup.

By contrapositive, if $T$ is a subgroup, then $G$ is cyclic of prime power order.

**Bonus.** Prove that if $|G|=p^n$ with $n\gt 1$, then $T$ is exactly the unique maximal subgroup of $G$, of order $p^{n-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your long detailed answer. But you answered only half of the problem right ? You prove that if $T$ is a subgroup, then $G$ is cyclic of prime power order, but you don't prove that if $G$ is cyclic of prime power order, then $T$ is a subgroup.

Comment: @Wicwan: That's what the "Bonus" part is. It is an extremely easy consequence of basic facts about cyclic groups and their subgroups.

Comment: How can I even be sure that $T$ is a subgroup of $G$ when $G$ is a cyclic group of prime power ?

Comment: @Wicwan By proving it?

Comment: Okay so as you say "if d divides |G| then G has a unique subgroup of order d and in particular has elements of order d". Now I take $a \in G$ of order $p$ and $b \in G$ of order $p^s$ with $s<n$. Now I know that $<a>$ and $<b>$ are both proper subgroups of G, so the union of both is in $T$. So now logically $a,b \in T$ and if $T$ is a subgroup of $G$, $ab$ should also be in $T$. But after this I don't know where to go.

Comment: @Wicowan: What do the words "**unique** maximal subgroup of $G$" mean to you?

Comment: a subgroup of $G$ such that no other subgroup contains it ?

Comment: @Wicowan: A maximal subgroup is a subgroup of $G$, *different from $G$*, that is not properly contained in any proper subgroup of $G$. But I said **unique** maximal subgroup. If a *finite* group $G$ has one and only one maximal subgroup, that tells you something about **every** subgroup of $G$ different from $G$.

Comment: maybe that every proper subgroup contained in the maximal subgroup forms a partially ordered set ? But I don’t really see the link… Or is it that the quotient $G/T$ is simple ?

Comment: @Wicowan Sigh... if every proper subgroup is contained in the unique maximal subgroup $M$, and $M$ itself is a proper subgroup, what is the union of all proper subgroups?

Comment: it's simply... M ?

Comment: @Wicowan And is that a subgroup?